# Disable CTRL+ALT+DELETE being sent to host while on VM

Tags: windows, vmware, ctrl-alt-delete

I need to disable CTRL+ALT+DELETE sequence being sent to to the host (Windows 8.1) while a Windows 7 VM is on.
I tried adding `mks.ctlAltDel.ignore = "TRUE"` to the VMX and/or config.ini file - but that doesn't seem to do anything!

BTW, I'm using VMware Workstation 14 Player.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: `mks.ctlAltDel.ignore = "TRUE"` - By itself doesn't ignore the keyboard shortcut in question.  To understand my comment read the [associated documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_special_config.html).  It is linked to the Isolation Tools.

Comment: Huh, just to be sure, have you tried to update VMware tools?

Comment: Yes. On both the PC and the laptop I'm testing I have the latest VMware Tools.

As I've stated below, enabling Enhanced Keyboard did the trick, but on the laptop it only works with an external keyboard! With the laptop's own keyboard, the CTRL+ALT+DELETE sequence is still being sent to the host instead of the VM. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the VMware enhanced keyboard driver, then Ctrl+Alt+Del will not be intercepted by the host.  However, I believe it's it's available as an option when installing VMware Workstation, not VMware Player.

Comment: The author is using the free version of VMWare Workstation which is basically what used to be called VMWare Player.  So basically the author cannot use the keyboard driver you reference

Comment: It seems like setting the Enhanced Keyboard option to "Required" did the trick! both CTRL+ALT+DEL and CTRL+ALT+INSERT are sent to the VM instead of the host - which is basically what I wanted :)
BTW, I'm indeed using the free version, which nowadays is called VMware Workstation 14 Player.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Apparently I was happy a little too soon... While it works as expected on a PC, it does not work on a laptop, using it's own keyboard. When connecting an external KB to the laptop - it works well again. Any way to overcome this obstacle??

Comment: @RanKedar That's really weird.  Was the VM powered on with the external KB already connected?

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm testing the VM on a PC and on a laptop. When I power on the laptop, without external KB - CTRL+ALT+DEL is redirected to the host. It's only after I connect an external KB that it's sent to the VM itself, and only by using the external KB (i.e. even with the ex. KB connected, CTRL+ALT+DEL will sent to the host).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible using the free VMware Player. CTRL-ALT-DEL is an interrupt. It is a set of keys that creates a privileged signal that is handled in specific ways by the hardware and then the software of the host.

In order for this keystroke to be intercepted, a special driver must be loaded which is only available in the not-free version of VMware Workstation.

However, due to the possibility you'll need to use CTRL-ALT-DEL to control the host, even if running the full-featured version of VMware Workstation it's better to become familiar with and use the alternate key combination VMware DOES support, CTRL-ALT-Insert, to send the interrupt command to the VM.

Comment: This is not quite correct.  See my answer.

Comment: VMware software can be configured to interpret CTRL-ALT-Insert as CTRL-ALT-DEL for the VM. VMware documentation confirms my answer: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/587 If you have facts indicating it is different, please present them.

Comment: Your answer implies that i's impossible, but it is (just not with VMware Player).  Please see https://communities.vmware.com/thread/572003 where a VMware employee (note the username) explains what the VMware keyboard driver does.

Comment: (BTW, that KB article was probably originally written a long time ago.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I'll try to get it corrected.)

Comment: Today I learned.